# Trigger copy in Chrome DevTools

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

Assume that we through JavaScript have added a method to the global/window object called  `logToken`, that we want to run from the developer console. It's function should be to log a token (string) and copy it to the clipboard. The code exists within a React project and is thus compiled with webpack. How could we achieve this?

We can't use `navigator.clipboard.writeText` because we get the error "Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Document is not focused", as the focus is in the developer console.

We can't use `copy()` because it's only defined in the developer console, not in your JavaScript. It **will** copy the token to the clipboard, but it will also throw a compilation error upon page load.

Is there any other way around this?

```js
window.logToken = () => {
  const token = 'my magic token';
  
  console.log(token);

  copy(dmdpToken); // works but throws an error on page load
  navigator.clipboard.writeText(token); // doesn't work and throws error
}
```

Comment: But why does it matter if `copy()` is only available in devtools, you want to run it from there anyway?

Comment: Use the deprecated document.execCommand: [How do I copy to the clipboard in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/400212)

Comment: Using `copy` triggers a compile error, edited the question to clarify.